# Should I be able to define a POST resource with optional message body?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenApi3 to define my API, and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin to generate spring REST controllers and models from the api definition.

I want to have an endpoint that takes an *optional* request body as JSON. A simplified example:

```
  /foo/{id}/bar:
      post: # ok
          parameters:
              - in: path
                name: id
                schema:
                    type: string
          requestBody:
              required: false
              content:
                  application/json:
                      schema:
                          type: object
                          properties:
                              bazuu:
                                  type: string
          responses:
              '200':
                  description: ok
```

According to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/,

> Request bodies are optional by default

I have still thrown in an extra `required: false` to try to make this request body optional (in vain). Attempting to call this endpoint without a request body causes:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> org.my.restapi.openapi.FooApiController.fooIdBarPost(java.lang.String,org.my.restapi.openapi.model.InlineObject11)
```

This is because the generator creates bazuu parameter as `@Valid @RequestBody InlineObject11 inlineObject11`. If I change RequestBody-annotation to required=false by hand, my endpoint accepts requests without a body, too.

Manually corrected one:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "fooIdBarPost", notes = "", authorizations = {
    @Authorization(value = "ApiKeyAuth")
}, tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "ok") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{id}/bar",
    consumes = { "application/json" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
default ResponseEntity<Void> fooIdBarPost(@ApiParam(value = "",required=true) @PathVariable("id") String id,@ApiParam(value = ""  )  @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) InlineObject11 inlineObject11) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

}
```

and wrapper class

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-06-10T12:43:04.880+03:00[Europe/Helsinki]")

public class InlineObject11   {
  @JsonProperty("bazuu")
  private String bazuu;

  public InlineObject11 bazuu(String bazuu) {
    this.bazuu = bazuu;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: File a bug report with the openapi-generator at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues

Comment: Created https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3134